# Is there a gramplet or report for getting the list of surnames from gramps?

Tags: gramps

I would like to get a text list of all the surnames in my gedcom from gramps. I can get a window with the info I need by using the 'statistics' gramplet and clicking on 'Unique Surnames'. This opens a 'quickview' window with the list but I can't seem to copy that list. I'm running on a mac and cmd-c doesn't seem to work on the list. Does anyone knows how to copy the info from quickview, or is there a different gramplet I should be using?

The 'top surname' and 'surname cloud' gramplets don't give the entire 732 surnames that I'm looking for (or at least I haven't figured out how to get them to).

I've looked thru the gramps wiki manual and not found the answer (but I'm guessing it is in there somewhere).

I know I can get into the source code if I have to but I'm hoping someone already has an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The top surnames gramplet can be configured to display this. Take note of the total number of surnames and navigate to `~/.gramps/Gramplets_grampletview_gramplets.ini` in your file browser. Open the file and scroll to the Top Surnames section. On the  `data[0]=10` line, change the 10 to the number of surnames that there are. Save and exit the file.

The surnames cloud gramplet can also be configured to do the same.

Answer (score 5):

I am sorry I can't help with a method of doing it in Gramps. However, Gramps can create a Gedcom file. There is a free on-line utility called Ged2Wordle that will do what you want. It is available [here](http://orba-design.com/genealogy/).

Disclaimer: I wrote this utility for someone else and it is my website.

Answer (score 2):

Gramps 4.2 now has a "Copy all" option on right-click that will allow copy to the clipboard from the quickview. Gramps 4.2 will probably be released later this year.